# Como permitir requisições cross-origin?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho um App em Swift que consome dados de uma API, em swift eu tive que habilitar no ***info.plist*** acrescentando:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Dai preciso habilitar o mesmo em angular, como é? vi em alguns lugares dizendo que precisa  fazer algo no servidor mas eu nem precisei...

**Mensagem:**

> Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same
>   Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em
>   http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments. (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente).

Answer (score 1):

Para desactivar a [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) experimenta inicar o Chrome com as seguintes flags:

`--disable-web-security --user-data-dir`

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Olá qual a linguagem de programação que você está usando no seu server(web services/API)?

Vou deixar um exemplo abaixo em php e pode ser feito facilmente em outras linguagens.

Para habilitar o CORS basta você retornar um header na página solicitada o header é o  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` e o valor dele é `*`

> Exemplo em PHP

```
<?php
        //habilitando o cors
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```